# ASP.net core MVC serving files best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file

I have an archive filled with files of different types, pictures, pdf etc, stored as byte arrays.

What would be the proper way to serve these files to a client? Is there any difference if that client is a browser, another web app, curl or something else?

As you may have noticed I am not familiar with serving files. Other than static files to a web page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I use `return File(content, contentType, fileName);` inside the controller. This will allow you to return any type of file whether images, pdf, xls, etc. I don't quite get the "proper way to serve these files to a client" part

Comment: Thank you, well I guess it might have been an unnecessary thing to write. I just wanted to ask what people thought was the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to serve binary data through an action is like the following:

```
    public IActionResult Foo()
    {
        return File(new byte[] { },"image/png");
    }
```

The client will not make a difference.